# Xamarin Date Format cannot be converted to type System.DateTime

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm facing this problem when I select a date from the DatePicker:

[image]

**Xaml code:**

```
<Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameStyle}">
    <controls:CustomEntry x:Name="DataDocEntry" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}', Source={x:Reference MainDatePicker}}" IsEnabled="false" Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" />
</Frame>
<DatePicker x:Name="MainDatePicker" Grid.Column="1" MinimumDate="1/1/2018" MaximumDate="12/31/2030" HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="Gray" Opacity="0"  />
<Image VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" Source="icalendar.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Calendario_Clicked" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

How can i handle this?

Best regards

Comment: is your device set to a locale that uses DD/MM/YYYY?  Or are you doing something to the locale settings in your code?

Comment: Where can i see that? I haven't changed anything

Comment: look at the date/language settings on the device/emulator

Comment: Date & Time settings are all automatic

Comment: {0:MMMM dd, yyyy} fixed it since it's the same format as the device thanks Jason!
I didn't know it needed to be the same!